# Flutter time picker with 1-12 in the outer circle, and 13-00 in the inner circle

Tags: android, flutter, timepicker

I'm using showTimePicker in flutter with 24 hour format.
My Code:

```
var selectDateTime = await showTimePicker(
              context: context,
              initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
              builder: (context, child) {
                return MediaQuery(
                  data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
                    alwaysUse24HourFormat: true,
                  ),
                  child: TimePickerDialog(
                    initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
```

Its showing Time Picker like this.
[image]

If alwaysUse24HourFormat:false then its showing.
[image]

I want to make it like this.
[image]

What should I do?

Comment: alwaysUse24HourFormat: false,

Comment: then its show am pm format, I want 24 hour format.